# spresense　サンプルプログラム　gnss_nmea.ino で　'GnssPositionData' does not name a type　が出てコンパイルできない。

Tags: spresense, arduino

下記のリンクで、copy raw fileして作成したgnss_nmea.inoをコンパイルすると'GnssPositionData' does not name a typeエラーで止まります。
ヘッダーファイルを追っかけてみるとGNSS.h -> GNSSPositionData.hに構造体があるのですが、参照できていないようです。エディタの設定など、何かうっかりがあるのでしょうか。
確認するところのヒントなどご教授ください。

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/blob/master/Arduino15/packages/SPRESENSE/hardware/spresense/1.0.0/libraries/GNSS/examples/gnss_nmea/gnss_nmea.ino#L37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

サンプルスケッチをコピーしてきて動かないということは、
使用しているライブラリとの互換性が取れていないだけかと思います。

使用しているSpresenseパッケージのバージョンが古かったりしないでしょうか？

ボードマネージャからSpresenseのバージョンを3.1.0(いまの最新)に更新すれば動作すると思います。

Comment: 助かりました、解決しました。昨年辺りからSpresenseを始めたので、「Spresense Arduino チュートリアル」の記事がSpresenseパッケージより古いと思い込んでSpresenseパッケージのバージョンが古いと考えませんでした。gnss_nmea.inoのコメント文をよく見ると確かに2023と書いてあり、リライトされていたのかもしれませんね。

Comment: Spresense Reference Board のバージョンは 2.6.0 でした。これが、3.1.0になり問題が解決しました。